# Battery dead. Why won't my car start when jumped?

Tags: battery, alternator, jump-start

I have a 2007 Lexus ES350 with about 185K miles on it. I've owned it for about 14 months, never had a problem.

Over the past couple of days it was sitting parked in my garage. I'm not sure, but the interior dome light could have been left on. When I tried to start it today, there was nothing. No response, no lights, no clicking. Absolute silence. Even the electric-powered door-locks and trunk-opener wouldn't work.

So I tried jumping the car. As soon as I connected the cables, all the electrical systems came to life: A/C, Headlights, dash lights, beeping, etc, etc.

However, when I tried to start the car while the cables were connected, it wouldn't start. I could hear the electrical clicking, but absolutely no turnover. Here's a short video: https://photos.app.goo.gl/E34619ZJL8JJAvV3A

Would a battery replacement likely fix this? Or is it something more serious?

Comment: Sounds to me like you've suffered from resting acid levels, When you put your multi-meter on it does it show a reading below 10.50 Volts Direct Current after an hour. That means your battery is junk, even a jump start wont start a battery that blew out one of its cells... This happens because the car sits too long and the alternator cant recharge the battery from short distances so the acid levels keep dropping while the owner wants more power, They try to start the car - Nothing, Jump start always works right. That's way too much power for low acid levels.. poof, the battery is done. Option 1

Comment: Option 2 - The Ignition switch might be faulty on the conductor that sends power out to the starters solenoid... Highly unlikely for one contact to go bad though... Start with testing the battery .. Option 3, solenoid and start went out at the same time, but again that's like throwing a rock across the pacific ocean, highly unlikely , - Option 4- You have a bad voltage regulator or rectifier on your alternator - This is a likely cause also, with the car running and the multi-meter on Volt AC you shouldnt have over .5 Volts on the battery and VDC shoul dbe between 13.2 - 15.2 which says your

Comment: regulator is working, Never jump start a car that's been resting or has under 11.50 volts, always use a battery charger

Comment: How long did you have the jumper cables on BEFORE you tried to start it?  Even with a good battery, recently run down, you will often have to wait a few minutes for the good battery to take some charge (over the cables) to assist with the starting of the engine.